# How can I create keyboard that open from bottom with animation?

Tags: android, animation

I want to create a dialer application for school, I saw that it could be done in another application.

Before the click on the :

[image: First Image]

After click:

[image: Second picture]

I do not know what the object that used in the images but I need to do this in my app.
I do not have code I wrote for it because I do not know what object to use.
I would be happy if you take the problem apart and help me to understand  what objects to use.

I could not find how to do this and would appreciate help.

Comment: Please provide some code for what you have tried and explain the issues that you encountered

Comment: I edited the question